# Issues with Android GeoCoder in Emulator

Tags: android, gps, geocoding, google-geocoder

I'm trying to get the city name from lat/long using getLocality() but I can't seem to get any data. Here is what I am trying to do but myList is always empty. After seeing this I used the isPresent() method of Geocoder and it returns false...does this mean the service is not working?

```
Geocoder myLocation = new Geocoder(getApplicationContext(), Locale.getDefault());
List<Address> myList = myLocation.getFromLocation(49.123124,-122.652404, 1);
```

I'm using the AVD_GalaxyNexusOne virtual device. From what I've read online some devices don't work with GeoCoder, is this one of them?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

there is a problem to use the geocoder services in emulator specially in emulator in versions 2.2 and 2.1 is a known bug.